# What is difference between inline post engagement and inline post engagement in actions?

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api

Facebook terms are very confusing and it is not explained very clearly. I am confused between `inline_post_engagement` and `actions > post_engagement` what is the difference between the two? I get different value at both the places. Here is a sample response from Fb

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "inline_post_engagement": "3257",
      "actions": [
        {
          "action_type": "page_engagement",
          "value": "14555"
        },
        {
          "action_type": "post_engagement",
          "value": "14433"
        }
      ],
      "date_start": "2017-06-21",
      "date_stop": "2017-09-18"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "MAZDZD",
      "after": "MAZDZD"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Inline post engagement is the total number of actions that people take involving your ads. Inline post engagements use a fixed 1-day-click attribution window. It should be a numeric string. On the other hand, an action is activity that happens as a result of your ad.

For example, if someone views your ad and then installs an app, that app install may be attributed to your ad. An action is attributed to your ad performance when it happens within 1 day of someone viewing your ad or 28 days of someone clicking or engaging with your ad.

So, basically, post engagement is a type of action (action is the main category, pe is a subcategory). Hope this helps.